The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. while call rest service to generate token in WCF 4.0
I am trying to call a rest service which is working fine in postman to generate OAuth token,but when I tried in WCF 4.0 code, I am getting an error

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

at this line of code
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

Can somebody guide me to fix this issue?
Is is my full code:
public static string GetAccessToken(string tokenUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret, string grantType)
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Prepare the data to post.
        var postData = @"client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId) + "&" +
                       @"client_secret " + Uri.EscapeDataString(clientSecret) + "&" +
                       @"grant_type=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(grantType);
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}


Issue is fixed ,there was missing = after client_secret and there was a space in client_secret beginning

Issue is fixed ,there was missing = after client_secret and there was a space in client_secret beginning
